# I cannot use the wifi interface of my M5StickCPlus. I get an error at execution time

Tags: c++, esp32

The code compiles. But, when I execute my code, the line `Wifi.begin(...)` is producing this error:

> [E][esp32-hal-cpu.c:93] addApbChangeCallback(): duplicate
> func=400EAB58 arg=3FFBF018.

What is going on?

Here is my code:

```
#include "M5StickCPlus.h"
#include <WiFi.h>


char WIFI_SSID[] =  "router";
const char* WIFI_PASS = "pass";

void setup() {
  M5.begin(true, true, true);
  Serial.printf("Connecting to %s ", WIFI_SSID);
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASS);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("CONNECTED");
}
```